# What's the issue in restricting the user to select value from auto populated list only in jQuery(i.e. user should not be able to enter new entry)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead, auto-populate

I'm using **jquery-1.9.1.min.js, PHP, MySQL, etc.** for my website. I'm using **Bootstrap's typeahed plugin** to achieve the auto populate functionality on a text field. AS user starts typing into the text field, at the back end I'm fetching the necessary matching data elements through AJAX, PHP and MySQL.

Till here everything is working fine for me. But one new requirement is there. I don't want to allow user to enter data other than the data items appeared in auto populated list. In other words, I want to restrict user to select data element from the matching auto populated list only. He/she shouldn't be able to enter data other than the entries present in auto populated data item list.

The **typeahead.js** has already been included.

For this I wrote following code but it didn't work for me. My logic is as follows:

As user starts typing in the matching data is elements are dynamically generated and auto populated below the text field. So, I think on "onBlur" event of the text field if I check whether the value contained in a text field is present in an matching data elements array or not. If it's not then just blank the textfield, alert the user to select value only from the matching auto populated list of items.

May be my logic is wrong. If someone can solve my issue in a more smarter way or just by modifying the code I written it will be of great help to me.

My HTML and jQuery code is as follows:

```
/*Here goes the HTML code*/
<form action="products.php" id="manage_product" name ="manage_product" role="form" class="form-horizontal col-md-12" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="admin_url" id="admin_url" value="http://localhost/xyz/pqr">
<input type="text" class="form-control dynamic_cat" size="20" autocomplete="on" id="product_type_id" name="product_type_id" value="">
</form> 

    /*Here goes the jQuery code*/
    $('.dynamic_cat').keyup(function() {
      $(".dynamic_cat").typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
          var textVal   = $(".dynamic_cat").val();
          var admin_url = $("#admin_url").val();

          $.ajax({
            url: admin_url+'modules/product_types/product_types.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'op=get_all_categories',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
              process(data);
            //console.log(textVal);
            }
          });
         }
       }).blur(function(data) {
         if ($.inArray($(this).val(), data) == -1) {
           $('.dynamic_cat').val('');
           alert("Please select the value only from list");
         }
       });
     });
```

The necessary PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
  $objProductType = new ProductType();
  switch( $op ) {
    case "get_all_categories":
      $ret = $objProductType->GetAllProductTypeNames();
      if(!$ret) { 
        $error_msg = $objProductType->GetAllErrors();
        list($data) = prepare_response($request);
        $smarty->assign('data', $data);
      } else {
        $grid_data = $objProductType->GetResponse();

        $category_name = '';

        for($i=0;$i<count($grid_data);$i++) {
          $category_name[] = $grid_data[$i]['category_name'];
        }
        echo json_encode($category_name);
        die;
      }      
    break;
  }
?>
```

Comment: I would go for checking input on every key stroke and on backend checking if the current input has matching results with wild cards %[INPUT]% .. if it returns successful show the list otherwise strip 1 character from the entered input ..

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the `.blur()` function is *inside* of `.keyup()`, which means you're adding a new listener every time a key is pressed. Similarly, you're re-binding the Typeahead.js plugin every time. You probably don't even need the `.keyup()` function – [typeahead.js will listen for keystrokes itself](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), and you only need to validate once you're sure the user is done typing (say, on the *change* event). Here's an example:

```
var $input = $(".dynamic_cat");

$input.typeahead({
  // ... 
}).on('change', function () {
  if ($.inArray($input.val(), data) == -1) {
    $input.val('');
    alert("Please select the value only from list");
  }
});
```

Disclaimer: In a production site, you'd want to always have validation on the backend (PHP, in this case) to make sure the inputs are valid. Think of JavaScript validation as a courtesy to the user, so s/he can get quicker feedback.